# Including None in dataframe filter

Tags: python, pandas, filter, isin

I have a dataframe called df:

```
     col1    col2
      1       2
      3       3
      7       8
      5       2
     12       8
      5       None
```

I want to use pandas.series.isin to filter the data frame, where I want to filter the data from df where the col2 only includes number 2,8 and None, so the new data frame is:

```
     col1    col2
      1       2
      7       8
      5       2
     12       8
      5       None
```

I tried:

```
filter1 = [2,8,'None']
filter2 = [2,8,np.nan]
filter3 = [2,8,'']

df.col2.isin(filter1)
df.col2.isin(filter2)
df.col2.isin(filter3)
```

And the result is always:

```
     col1    col2
      1       2
      7       8
      5       2
     12       8
```

it seems I am unable to identify what is None and how to include it into the filter.

Comment: `'None'` should be `None`.

Comment: `df where the col2 only includes number 2,8 and None`...What if there's a `NaN` in `col2` should output df include `NaN` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude the '' when passing None in your filter

```
filter1 = [2,8,None]
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to include any null value:

```
filter = df['col2'].isin([2,8]) | df['col2'].isnull()
df_filtered = df.loc[filter]
```